# Can't move at all after stopping movement on collision check

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent movement in X/Y direction when you collide with X/Y wall. The problem I'm having with this code is when you do collide, the player stops, but all other input is also blocked.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 87: // W
            if(b.hit(ENT_PLAYER, ENT_WALL_X)) break;
            ENT_PLAYER.y -= 10;
            break;
        case 83: // S
            if(b.hit(ENT_PLAYER, ENT_WALL_X)) break;
            ENT_PLAYER.y += 10;
            break;
        case 68: // D
            if(b.hit(ENT_PLAYER, ENT_WALL_Y)) break;
            ENT_PLAYER.x += 10;
            break;
        case 65: // A
            if(b.hit(ENT_PLAYER, ENT_WALL_Y)) break;
            ENT_PLAYER.x -= 10;
            break;
    }
});
```

Maybe I'm too tired to figure this one out, but I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing any other DOM manipulation when the event fires? You state all inputs are blocked it sounds like the DOM may be getting recreated which could blow away the event listener. Do you have any debugging breakpoints setup and are using dev tools. If dev tools is open you may be breaking/pausing on a line of code and not be aware of it.